# Shopify to Woocommerce customer migration

Tags: woocommerce, migration, shopify

Is it possible to migrate customer data from current Shopify online store to newly developing Woocommerce store? (including customer passwords)

Litextension caught my eyes since it seems only they say they can do it but I'm not sure if I can trust them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried this migration service: [Shopify to WooCommerce](https://next-cart.com/product/shopify-to-woocommerce/)? It says that it is possible to migrate customer + passwords for free.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had to did this in my previous workplace, it requires an external service (Unless you build one yourself), which will almost always cost.
We used [Cart2Cart](https://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/shopping-cart-migration-options/6694-woocommerce-to-shopify-migration) for our migration.

The weird thing was, it did actually import the customer's details, orders, passwords etc, but it wouldn't let them log in. So the customer had to register again with their previous email and password and they'd have all of their past orders on their account.